# Reading URL Anchor on IE

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I've got a page full of links to another page with anchors on the end (like this: index.html#anchor). On the page they point to, I have a script that is supposed to read where the anchor points to in order to display something.

On firefox it works perfectly, But I've noticed that IE seems to remove the #anchor from the end of the url, so the script can't grab the text. Is there a way around this, without any server side code?

Answer (score 5):

How is it getting the url?

`window.location.hash` should [contain the contents of the hash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535866%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: That's how I've been getting it in the script, but it seems IE removes the hash from the url once it's loaded. not sure why, or even if there is a solution. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

I've tested the following code in IE 6, 7, and 8, and the correct hash is shown in the alert box in all cases.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function showHash() {
        var currentUrl = "" + document.location;
        var hash = "";
        var parts = currentUrl.split("#");
        if (parts.length > 1) {
            hash = parts[1];
        }
        alert("the current hash is: " + hash);
    }

</script>

<input type="button" value="Show Hash" onclick="javascript: showHash();" />
```

Does that code work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Does `window.location` still contain the anchor on IE, or is it removed there also? If it's still there you could use `window.location` and split on the hash:

```
var whole = "" + window.location;  // location is object, make sure it's a String
var parts = whole.split('#');
var anchor = parts[1];
```

Comment: IE doesn't seem to keep it in the window.location. Thanks for your idea though!

Comment: that doesn't work either i'm afraid. It gives the same result as window.location

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this

```
    var url = window.location.search.substring(1)
    var arr=url.split("#")
    str=arr[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that helps. It returns null if there's no anchor.
I placed it inside an Util.js, it comes in handy :D

```
function getAnchor() {
    var currentUrl = document.URL,
        urlParts   = currentUrl.split('#');

    return (urlParts.length > 1) ? urlParts[1] : null;
}
```